# scraping probsssss

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

> I have two questions.
>
> 1. I am trying to get the value of propval, but when I run the scraper I just get an emptying string back. **Should I use a different method
>      besides filter or am I not choosing the right element?** I've tried
>      different elements, but it does the same thing.
> 2. Can I use a loop to go through every single table row to collect all the prop value ids or is there a more efficient way?

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {


url = 'http://streak.espn.com/en/';

request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var gameQuestion, propVal;
        var json = { gameQuestion : "", propVal : ""};

        $('.gamequestion').each(function(){
            var data = $(this)
            gameQuestion = data.text();

            json.gameQuestion = gameQuestion;

        })

        $('a#.matchupDiv').each(function() {
            var data = $(this);

            propVal = data.text();

            json.propVal = propVal;
        })
    }


    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err){

        console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
    })

    res.send('Check your console!')

   });
})



app.listen('8081')

console.log('magic happens on port 8081');

exports = module.exports = app;

<tbody>
    <tr> 
        <td rowspan = "2" class='mg-column1 start'></td>
        <td rowspan = "2" class='mg-column2 start'></td>
        <td rowspan = "2" class='mg-column3 start'></td>
            <div class="mg-check" propval="m57207o58439" name="matchupDiv">nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery `.filter()` function takes either an element, a selector, a function, or another jQuery object (http://api.jquery.com/filter/). Since you are passing a function into the filter, it is expecting you to return a boolean (a true/false value).

What you probably want to use is the `.each()` function. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). When you query a class, you will get back an array of matching objects. `.each()` will loop through the array and you could do what you are trying to do there. Give it a shot.

ADDED***** I was looking at the source code, and there is no class `propval`. You need to change your query to:

`$('.mg-check').attr('propVal')`

But `.mg-check` doesn't appear to have any children. What are you trying to scrape exactly?

EDITED *** To get an array of the propVals, try this:

Change your initialization of your `json.propVal` from `''` to `[]`, then...

`$('.mg-check').each(function(){ json.propVal.push($(this).attr('propVal')) });`

Comment: can you use the `.each()` method on `$('.mg-check').attr('propVal')`?

Comment: `$('.mg-check')` will return an array of elements, since there are multiple elements with that class. Maybe the better syntax will be: `$('.mg-check').each(function(){ json.propVal.push($(this).attr('propVal'))});` to store the propVals in an array. Meaning you need to change you initialization of `json.propVal` (and of `json.gameQuestion`) to be an empty array. This way you could use the push method on your `gameQuestion` as well so you will have an array of questions, not just the last question in the